# getting this issue *Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.*

Tags: java, android, error-handling

I am trying to build my app in android studio and getting this error and I am tired of clearing it,

```
/Users/mac/Desktop/appname/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:
uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: It's a warning triggered by casting without checking if it is an instance of the class. You can ignore it if you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Zoe but I can not build my app!

Comment: Welp, that ain't the reason. Create a [mcve]